# Does the following class of functions have a name?

Tags: terminology

Consider the functions $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{C}$ that can be expressed as $\mathbb{C}$-linear combinations of functions of the form $g(n)=n^d\zeta^n$, where $d\geq 0$ is an integer and $\zeta$ is a root of unity. They are the functions which satisfy a homogeneous linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients such that the characteristic roots are roots of unity.

Do such functions have a name? Are they familiar things in any corner of mathematics?

Comment: I think some people call these quasi-polynomials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-polynomial

Comment: Great! Please post this as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

A linear recurrence is often said to be *degenerate* if the ratio of two of its characteristic roots is a root of unity. Many arithmetic results on values of linear recurrences only hold for non-degenerate sequences, e.g., the Skolem-Mahler-Lech theorem. So although I haven't seen the term used before, it seems as if *totally degenerate linear recurrence* might be appropriate (although your sequences even have the individual characteristic roots as roots of unity, so maybe "extra-totally..."!).